# Python SpeechRegonition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I write a little program which writes the audio to text. But it throws an error and I don't know how to fix it.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

file_name = "halloWelt.wav"

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(file_name) as file:
    data = speech_engine.record()
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(data, language='de-DE')
    print(text)
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 203, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 509, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 130, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 208, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.initfp(file_object)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 316, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with FORM id')
aifc.Error: file does not start with FORM id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 234, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(aiff_file, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\aifc.py", line 314, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\\OneDrive\Dokumente\Programming\Python\Lets code\speech.py", line 6, in <module>
    with sr.AudioFile(file_name) as file:
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 236, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

Comment: you should add the source  `data = speech_engine.record(file)`

Comment: `ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format` <- Looks like there is an error with your audio file. Can you make the question reproducible by adding it or another sample to your question?